# Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, parsing

Trying to Parse the price from a site. I can already retrieve the title from the source but i get a Notice when i attempt to scrape the price.
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 
Here's the code:

```
<?php

$file_string = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com');

preg_match('/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i', $file_string, $title); 
$title_out = $title[1];

preg_match('~<span id="ref_658274_l">(.*)</span>~', $file_string, $price);
//error on the line below 
$price_out = $price[1];

?>

<?php echo "$title_out"; ?>
<?php echo "$price_out"; ?>
```

Comment: What does the price like looks like?

Comment: Your regular expression isn't matching. We can't tell you any more than this.

Comment: The price is plain text and its currently 2.60 the [1] is standard i dont understand why its having the issue it worked with $title

Comment: @user1248404 if the id is no good, then it can cause the error. You could also try to escape the / to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing HTML may be more successful with [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com'));

$titleElems = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
if ($titleElems->length) {
  $title = $titleElems->item(0)->nodeValue;
}

$priceElem = $doc->getElementById('ref_658274_l');
if ($priceElem != null) {
  $price = $priceElem->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: do i place this in a php file?

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression doesn't match. When using the result, you should always validate that the index you are using, in this case `1`, is within the bounds of your `array`.